# react-native init versus Expo for new React Native project?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, expo

I am completely new to React Native and I would like to develop my first RN app. I have experience with React and building iOS apps with Swift, but I have never tried React Native.

I see that there are two main ways of creating a new app, either with `react-native init` or through Expo. Which is the preferred toolchain for someone of my experience? Can somebody explain the tradeoffs between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to learn, I would suggest you to use the cli.

The main difference between react-native init and expo is that you cant add native modules and can't use packages with native language that require linking. Overall if you are creating a small project that doesn't require functionalities that the cli, go for expo. But if you are builidng a decently large project or if you are just trying to learn your ways around react native, I would chose the cli. IMHO